# What kind of react-native component can i use to replicated the one on the following picture?

Tags: react-native

I would like to use something similar on my application, it's a component that display cells, and create a new one when the previous one has been filled.

Do you know how this component is named, or something similar? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [react-native-super-grid](https://github.com/saleel/react-native-super-grid) library. It is quite flexible and will give the required UI.

You can use the `FlatGrid` component from this library,

```
<FlatGrid
  itemDimension={130}
  items={[1,2,3,4,5,6]}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (<Text>{item}</Text>)}
/>
```

The `items` array can be generated as per your use case, and the `itemDimension` can also be set dynamically.

Comment: I will give it a try and let you know how it went. Thank you.